# How to setup annotation processor in maven-compiler-plugin with no derived marker on generated java files

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

Currently all generated java files and gen folder are marked as derived so I'm not able to checkin these files. Is there any compiler arg or confguration which I can use to disable this marking in maven-compiler-plugin?
If it is not possible to achieve it with maven-compiler-plugin is there any plugin which could generate the code without marking the files as derived?